# Switch statement in PHP does not recognize special characters (i.e. UTF-8)!

Tags: php, utf-8, case, switch-statement

I have one switch statement in my PHP code and it seems it doesn't execute case with the UTF-8 character even though value put to switch is UTF-8 character. It works with all other characters.

CODE:

```
echo $word[$i];

switch($word[$i]){

 case "a": echo "aaaa"; break;

 case "č": echo "aaaa"; break;
}
```

If the $word[$i] is "a" the code echoes "a" and "aaaa" if the $word[$i] is "č" the code echoes "č" but does not echo "aaaa". It simply ignores case with "č". I also tried case with single quotes.

Comment: If you are using data from a database maybe you could use this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Else make sure your encoding is the same in the file and in the database!

Comment: Works for me. @Dennis is probably right, there's probably a mix-up between your script and the database (or whatever input method you are using).

Comment: Are you sure all data is using the same encoding?

Comment: Data is not used from database. It is from a form from index.php. The encoding in this php and index.php is same(utf-8 w/o BOM), DOCTYPE is set, meta Content-Type is set in the head. It does not work even though I hardcode value right before execution of switch. And like I said, "echo" before switch always correctly outputs "č" even though switch ignores it. Thanks for help though! :)

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a function in PHP for setting the charset.. My god after a whole day working my brain can't remember the name.. Give me a second for searching :D

Comment: You can use the headers for setting the PHP charset.. If it isn't done "right" in your server setup. Try this:
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: I have this one set in the begining of my php script already, but sadly it doesn't do any good :)

Comment: Can you give us the output of `echo rawurlencode($word[$i])` when you believe the character should be `č`?  Compare the results with `echo rawurlencode('č');`  I'm going to be that *one* of those is the expected UTF-8 sequence, while the other isn't.

Comment: I got: raw word: %C4 raw char: %C4%8D raw word: %8D raw char: %C4%8D, where word is result of: echo rawurlencode($word[$i]) and char of: echo rawurlencode('č');. I noticed it runs 2x times even though everything is inside "for" loop which should run once. I then noticed it must be problem with str_split() function I am using. print_r returns: Array ( [0] => a ) if I input "a" and it returns: Array ( [0] => � [1] => � ) if I input "č". The value of string before applying str_split() is correct - "č". Sorry for this messing problem :)

Comment: From official PHP forum someone said: It seems that this function splits according to byte-length and not character length. So if the letter "Å" takes 2 bytes, then str_split() will only return the first bite of the character "Å". So this was the problem in my case. It is also official PHP bug: [link](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37661) It seems I have to find another function to split my string into array. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will someday need to use "str_split" for utf-8 strings here is working function:

```
function str_split_utf8 ($string, $split_length = 1)
{
 $length = (int) $split_length;
 $string = (string) $string;

if ($length < 1)
{
 return false;
}

return preg_split("/(.{{$length}})/us", $string, -1,
PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
}
```

Comment: True. Thanks for pointing out solution by using multi byte functions. :)